# Need to make row-column-row using css flexbox

Tags: html, css

I want to make a row-column-row layout using css flexbox, here's the code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.2%;
}

.box {
  color: white;
  background: royalblue;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.b1 {
  flex: 1 0 80%;
}

.b2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.b3 {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box b1">1</div>
  <div class="box b2">2</div>
  <div class="box b3">3</div>
</div>
```

This is what I want:

[image]

And on mobile I want something like this:

[image]

But as you can see in the code, the column is not growing vertically and I cannot even use `margin`s or `gap`s in between the `div`s.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. CSS-Grid solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Why not use CSS grid instead?

Comment: Will css-grid help in this situation? Like I want to float the 2nd column in between in 1 & 3 on mobile, so is it possible?

Comment: Please put the code you have right in the question **here**, not on an external code site. Use a snippet (edit your question, then click the icon that resembles `<>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grid-based approach using a media query:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-template-areas:
    "b1 b2"
    "b3 b2";
  gap: 0.2%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "b1"
      "b2"
      "b3";
  }
}

.box {
  color: white;
  background: royalblue;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.b1 {
  grid-area: b1;
}

.b2 {
  grid-area: b2;
}

.b3 {
  grid-area: b3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box b1">1</div>
  <div class="box b2">2</div>
  <div class="box b3">3</div>
</div>
```